# Proving Not Big Omega?

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity, complexity-theory, proof

I'm trying to prove that *k(n*^2) is not Big Omega of 2^*n* where *k* is a positive real number. I've looked at the negation of Big Omega. So I'm trying to find a *n* that's greater than or equal to some *n0* that also satisfies *k*(*n*^2) < (2^*n*)*c* where *c* is a positive real number.

I've tried choosing an n where n = 2^*n0* and this makes *n*^2 = 2^*n* but the issue is that for the inequality to work, *k* has to be less than *c* and I can't choose what *k* and *c* are. I've tried to solve for n in the inequality by taking the log of both sides but then I end up with log(*b*) - log(*c*) < 2log(*n*) + *n*log(2) and I'm not exactly sure how to isolate for *n* in that case either. Any hints would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For a real proof, *always* start with the definition.

k(n^2) is OMEGA(2^n) if and only if there exists two constants c>0 and d>0 such that for all n > d, it's true that k(n^2) > c(2^n) .

To prove a negative, you'll almost always do best to use *contradiction*. Assume what you're trying to prove is *true* and deduce logically from this an assertion that's obviously false.

Consequently, assume k(n^2) is OMEGA(2^n) and so c and d as described above do exist.

Then we know

```
For all n > d, n^2 > (c/k)(2^n)
```

and

```
For all n > d, 2 log_2 n > log_2(c/k) + n
```

To show this is ridiculous, pick n = c/k.

The rest follows by algebra with a little sprinkling of calculus if you really want to be thorough. I'll let you work it out. [Hint](https://www.google.com/search?q=graph%20x%20-%20log%20x&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS847US847&oq=graph%20x%20-%20log%20x&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.8217j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: If n = c/k then how do I know that n > d?

Answer (score 0):

Assume kn^2 is Omega(2^n). Then for n >= n0 and a positive constant c, k*n^2 >= c*2^n. Dividing through by the RHS (which we can do since it must be positive), we get (k/c)n^2/2^n >= 1. Consider the limit of the LHS as n approaches infinity:

```
  lim(n->inf) (k/c)n^2/2^n              LHS
= (k/c) lim(n->inf)n^2/2^n              lim cf(x) = c lim f(x)
= (k/c) lim(n->inf)2n/((ln2)2^n)        l'Hopital's rule
= (k/c)(2/ln2) lim(n->inf)n/2^n         lim cf(x) = c lim f(x)
= (k/c)(2/ln2) lim(n->inf)1/((ln2)2^n)  l'Hopital's rule
= (k/c)(2/(ln2)^2) lim(n->inf)1/2^n     lim cf(x) = c lim f(x)
= 0                                     lim 1/f(x) = 0 if lim f(x) -> inf
```

The limit of the LHS for increasing n is zero. Therefore, for any interval around zero, there is an n which will put the value of the LHS within that interval. Choose the interval to be 0.5. Then there is an n that makes the inequality false. All that remains is to show that the LHS represents a monotonically decreasing function of n; we can calculate the derivative:

```
  d/dn (k/c)n^2/2^n                           LHS
= (k/c) d/dn n^2/2^n                          d/dx cf(x) = c d/dx f(x)
= (k/c) d/dn (n^2)(2^-n)                      1/2^x = 2^-x
= (k/c) (d/dn n^2)(2^-n) + (n^2)(d/dn 2^-n)   product rule of differentiation
= (k/c) (2n)(2^-n) + (n^2)((-ln2)(2^-n))      d/dx x^k = kx^(k-1), chain rule
= (k/c) [(-ln2)n^2 + 2n]/(2^n)                algebraic rearrangement
```

This is negative whenever (-ln2)n^2 + 2n < 0...

```
(-ln2)n^2 + 2n < 0
((-ln2)n + 2)n < 0
(-ln2)n + 2 < 0
(ln2)n > 2
n > 2/ln(2)
```

This means that at least for n > 4 the function is monotonically decreasing. If the assumed n0 is greater than 4, no problem. If the assumed n0 were less than 4, we'd be free to reassign n0 to n0' = 5 because the choice of n0 is unimportant so long as it works.